# How do I create a solid semi circle shape in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

Like this:

[image]

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Open a new document. Create a New Layer. Select Marquee Tool. Press Shift and Draw a circle. Alt + Delete and color fill the layer.

Step 2: Double click on the layer. Select Stroke - Select color and size of the border as per your requirement.

Step 3: Ctrl + J to duplicate the layer.

Step 4: Ctrl+T and reduce the size of the circle.

Step 5: Ctrl + Select the small circle layer. Once the small circle is selected, click the big circle layer and delete

Step 6: Deselect the selection and hide the small circle layer.

Step 7: Select Rectangular marquee tool. Create a rectangle and delete the selection. Your semi circle is ready.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create it as a vector shape, then proceed as follows:

1. Drop a horizontal and vertical guide so you can use the intersection as the centre of the circle.
2. Select the Ellipse Tool
3. Mouse over the intersection of the two guides.
4. As you begin clicking and dragging with the Ellipse Tool, hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.  This will constrain the shape to a circle centred on the origin of the guide intersection.
5. Mouse over the circle and hold down <kbd>ALT</kbd>. The cursor will display a little minus sign, to show that the next shape you create will be subtracted from the top shape.
6. As you begin clicking and dragging with the Ellipse Tool to create the inner circle, while still holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd>, also hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, as you click and drag.  This will subtract the top shape from the bottom.
7. Choose the Rectangle Tool.  In the tool options along the top choose the Subtract Front Shape option.
8. Click and drag a rectangle shape over the bottom half of the circle.
9. Hide the vector paths by selecting another tool, such as the Move tool.

[image]